# Adding html tag inside javascript string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code in react js:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    homePage: {
        sliderTitle: 'Creative portfolio',

        loginTitle: 'Do you already <b>have</b> an account?'

    },
    registrationPage: {
        foo: 'bar'
    }
};
```

When I try to use those labels I have

```
var EN = require('./en');
{EN.homePage.loginTitle}
```

but `{EN.homePage.loginTitle}` returns the string with b tags inside.

How can I apply this b tag to the word have?

Comment: You should probably use the Dangerously set innerHTML attribute, like proposed here: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html

Comment: I tried with `loginTitle: {__html: 'Do you already <b>have</b> an account?'}` , but the same problem.

Comment: and you also passed it as `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop to the div? like `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={EN.homePage.loginTitle} />`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option as mentioned in the comments is to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` assigning `loginTitle` a `__html` object (note the double underscore '__') and passing it to the element as a prop.

```
loginTitle: {__html: 'Do you already <b> have </b> an account?' }
...
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={EN.homePage.loginTitle}></div>
```

Generally speaking though you should avoid using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` whenever possible as emphasized in the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html

There are other safer options to insert HTML in your text outlined here: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html

One that should work well for you in this situation is to used a mixed array of strings & JSX, so:

```
loginTitle: ['Do you already ', <b>have</b>, ' an account']
...
<p>{EN.homePage.loginTitle}</p>
```

Here's a [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqoGLR) as well just to illustrate that both approaches have the same effect.

Comment: One could argue that there are indeed specific use cases for dangerouslySetInnerHTML, so don't feel bad using it! For example, string data that we are parsing from an API response can be parsed by wrapping a `<span>` tag for certain words to be styled differently. As long as this html ISN'T ABLE TO BE SET BY THE USER then there shouldn't be any harm in using dangerouslySetInnerHTML.